# Simulations with Columns as Input for Each Row in R

Tags: r, simulation

I'm trying to run a simulation with a combination of static variables and values within columns, sum the output, and store the individual outputs in a vector or dataframe.

```
mean1 <- 2.4
sd1 <- 0.5
df <- data.frame(x = c(2, 3, 4), y = c(5, 6, 7))
```

What I want to do is :

1. divide each row in column x by each row in column y
2. multiply by a normal distribution using mean1 and sd1
3. sum the resultant row values, so I'd have a single value per simulation.

I think I understand how I'd get the value if I wasn't going row by row, so for row 1 it'd be:

```
v1 <- replicate(n = 1, expr = rnorm(n = 100, mean = mean1, sd = sd1) * 2 / 5, simplify = TRUE)
```

But where I'm drawing a blank is how to run that for each row, then sum the results of each row for each simulation, in this case sum the three values from each of the three rows 100 times, so I'd have an output with 100 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing `x` by `y` is constant so you can do it once and save it in a variable. You can then use `replicate` 100 times and generate 1 random number at every iteration to multiply and take `sum`.

```
val <- df$x/df$y
n <- 100
replicate(n, {
  sum(val * rnorm(n = 1, mean = mean1, sd = sd1))
})
```

Or you can also generate 100 random values together and sum them with `sapply`.

```
r_val <- rnorm(n, mean = mean1, sd = sd1)
sapply(r_val, function(x) sum(val * x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ronak answered my question with:

```
val <- df$x/df$y
n <- 100
replicate(n, {
  sum(val * rnorm(n = 1, mean = mean1, sd = sd1))
})
```

I had to add back the df$column reference (df$x here) as opposed to creating a constant since the actual application had more variables and math that was more complicated than the example, but the structure worked perfectly.

Thank you!